# Infinite continued Fraction in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to implement a function that approximate the e constant in Python.

```
from fractions import Fraction


def fractionalSum(number, array):
    def inside(index, place):
        if place >= 0:
            return Fraction(1, index + place)
        else:
            return Fraction(1, index)

    if number == 0:
        return 0
    elif number == 1:
        return inside(array[number - 1], 0)
    elif number == 2:
        return inside(1, fractionalSum(number - 1, array))
    elif number == 88:
        return inside(array[0], inside(array[1], inside(array[2], inside(array[3], inside(array[4], 0)))))
    else:
        return inside(fractionalSum(number - 2, array), inside(fractionalSum(number - 1, array), 0))


expansion = [1]
it = 1
clock = 0
for i in range(1, 110):
    if clock == 0:
        expansion.append(2 * it)
        it += 1
        clock = 2
    if clock != 0:
        expansion.append(1)
        clock -= 1
print(expansion)
print(2 + fractionalSum(3, expansion))
```

I am currently trying recursion to calculate it but the code is not producing the correct results.

In the `fractionalsum` function having number 2 should call the same function with `number-1` but the results is wrong.

`number = 88` produces the correct value for number 5. I am trying to implement it recursively to approximate it with numbers > 50.

Comment: If your question related to the function FractionalSum, why did you include the expansion sequence.  Reduce your example to the minimal code required to demonstrate your problem, or at a minimum give us the original input to FractionalSum

Answer (score 0):

I haven't investigated what exactly you may have done wrong, but a recursive implementation of *Continued Fraction* should be fairly simple, so I'm suggesting this instead:

```
ONE = Fraction(1, 1)

def continuedFraction(array):
    return _continuedFraction(array, 0)

def _continuedFraction(array, index):
    result = Fraction(array[index], 1)
    if index + 1 < len(array):
        return result + ONE / _continuedFraction(array, index + 1)
    return result
```

Comment: Why a separate function? Arguments can have default values

Comment: @PranavHosangadi: The first one is meant to be your API (user) function, while the second one is meant to be an internal function, not visible to your users. You don't want your users to ask themselves what value they should pass for the `index` parameter, because it's an internal implementation detail, which is irrelevant to them